# How to install and use LibCURL with Code::Blocks in Elementary OS Luna

Tags: c++, ubuntu, codeblocks, libcurl

This might be a really silly question, but I'm new with Linux and I starting using Elementary OS (LUNA), so, I want to start with a C++ project that requires LibCURL, I already installed but when I try to use it with Code::Blocks, I just can't build the program even when I already add LibCURL as a static library.

Someone that could bring light to my mind?